# Filter in Java when meeting conditions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There is a condition that I need values in the following `Set`

```
Set<String> name = studentResponse
                    .stream()
                    .map(StudentResponse::getDetails)
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .map(StudentDetail::getName())
                    .filter(s -> s.contains("A"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I want to filter student names containing "A" if `List<StudentDetail> details` in `StudentResponse` contains more than 5 elements. If not, I want to take all names in `StudentDetail`.  Is there any way to handle this condition?

Comment: please clear this _if there is more than 5 details in StudentResponse_

Comment: What should happen if there are 5 or fewer "details" ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean with condition if `List<StudentDetail> details ` in `StudentResponse` contains more than 5 elements

Comment: something like this `.map(StudentResponse::getDetails)
                     .filter(d->d.size()>5)
                    .flatMap(List::stream)....`

Comment: @HadiJ I want to retrieve all data even though the size `StudentResponse::getDetails` < 5, but if more than 5, I only take the name that contains "A"

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Set<String> name = studentResponse
    .stream()
    .map(StudentResponse::getDetails)
    .flatMap(l -> l.stream()
        .map(StudentDetail::getName)
        .filter(s -> l.size() <= 5 || s.contains("A")))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

but it has the disadvantage of re-checking a list condition for every element, despite it shouldn't change during the entire traversal. A better solution is not to perform a `filter` operation when it is not necessary, like

```
Set<String> name = studentResponse
    .stream()
    .map(StudentResponse::getDetails)
    .flatMap(l -> l.size() <= 5?
        l.stream().map(StudentDetail::getName):
        l.stream().map(StudentDetail::getName).filter(s -> s.contains("A")))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or, to avoid the code duplication:

```
Set<String> name = studentResponse
    .stream()
    .map(StudentResponse::getDetails)
    .flatMap(l -> {
        Stream<String> names = l.stream().map(StudentDetail::getName);
        return l.size() <= 5? names: names.filter(s -> s.contains("A"));
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: This is clean! To answer the other comment - of course, If I would have thought of "partitioning" while flat mapping!

Answer (score 1):

You can try out processing the two halves based on the conditions using `partitioningBy`.

```
Map<Boolean, List<StudentResponse>> greaterThanFive = studentResponse.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(sr -> sr.getDetails().size() > 5));

Set<String> names = Stream.concat(
        greaterThanFive.get(Boolean.FALSE).stream()
                .flatMap(sr -> sr.getDetails().stream())
                .map(StudentDetail::getName),
        greaterThanFive.get(Boolean.TRUE).stream()
                .flatMap(sr -> sr.getDetails().stream())
                .map(StudentDetail::getName)
                .filter(name -> name.contains("A"))) // for details size more than 5
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

But there is no reason to choose it over a solution that can perform the [partitioning on-the-fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60885339/1746118).

Comment: Why not something like `greaterThanFive .entrySet() .flatMap(e -> e.getKey()? e.getValue() .stream() .flatMap(sr -> sr.getDetails().stream()) .map(StudentDetail::getName) .filter(name -> name.contains("A")): e.getValue() .stream().flatMap(sr -> sr.getDetails().stream()) .map(StudentDetail::getName)) ...`? Though, I don't know why you decided to perform a partitioning first, instead of doing either stream operation on-the-fly...

Answer (score 1):

Other way is using `Supplier<T>`

```
Supplier<Stream<List<StudentDetail>>> stuSup = ()-> studentResponse
                .stream()
                .map(StudentResponse::getDetails);
```

then perform a filter on it.

```
 Stream<String> gtFive = stuSup.get()
                .filter(d->d.size()>5)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(StudentDetail::getName())
                .filter(s -> s.contains("A"));
```

and for less than five:

```
Stream<String> lteFive = stuSup.get()
                .filter(d->d.size()<=5)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(StudentDetail::getName());
```

and finally, combine both of them.

```
Stream.concat(gtFive,lteFive).collect(toSet());
```

Comment: Which essentially does the same thing as *iterating twice on the complete list* of `studenResponse.getStudentDetails()` similar to the `partitioningBy` approach as well. +1 for an alternate to be chosen based on the extensibility and readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map.Entry` as a bag to collect all informations that are needed in the last filtering.

```java
Set<String> name = studentResponse
        .stream()
        .flatMap(sr -> sr.getDetails().stream().map(
            d -> Map.entry(sr.getDetails().size(), d.getName())))
        .filter(e -> (e.getKey() <= 5) || (e.getKey() > 5 && e.getValue().contains("A")))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```